# How to create an dynamic unordered list but keep a selected result on top

Tags: php, html, css

Im creating an HTML/CSS list that will be updated dynamically, however every new item in the list is placed in the top of the list. Is there anyway i can pin/stick a certain item of the list at the top and every new added item in the list placed under the top pinned one.

Here is the php and html code responsible for the adding items to the list

```
<ul class="list-items">
<?php foreach($jobs[$category->id] as $job): ?>
<li>
<a class="list-group-item tabledisplay <?php if ($job->is_featured): ?>job-highlight<?php endif; ?>" href="<?php _e(BASE_URL ."jobs/{$job->id}/". slugify($job->title ." {$lang->t('jobs|at')} ". $job->company_name)); ?>">
    <span class="job-company"><?php _e($job->company_name); ?></span>&nbsp;
    <span class="job-title"><?php _e($job->title); ?></span>
    <span class="badgee pull-right"><?php niceDate($job->created); ?></span>

</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Sounds possible. Can you create a [mcve] for how you're currently adding items?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have added the code.

Comment: What property of `$job` determines which one is supposed to be pinned to the top?

Comment: Each topic added to the database is placed as $job. The item itself is all whats between <li> and </li>

Comment: I would add a field `pinned` to the DB table, setting  "1" to the job post that should be pinned to the top and "0" to the rest. Then using `ORDER BY pinned DESC, {othersorting...}` to sort the data already in the model stage.

Comment: @jtheman Yes this how it should be, same as the `($job->is_featured)` how the code will be using `ORDER BY pinned` in the foreach?

Comment: @Fat-Bee please edit your question and add the SQL query you use to get your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would suffice:

```
<?php
$index = 3;
$featured= $jobs[$index];
unset($jobs[$index]);
?>
<ul>
    <li><?= $featured->title ?></li>
    <?php foreach($jobs as $job){ ?>
        <li><?= $job->title ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

## Breakdowm

Ill try to breakdown the code for you.

1. I am assumming `$jobs` is an array of objects. This is usually what we work with when retrieve data from the DB. For example lets say its something like this:

   ```
    $jobs = [
        (object)[
           'title' => 'something',
           'is_featured' => true,
        ],
        (object)[
           'title' => 'whatev',
           'is_featured' => false,
        ],
        (object)[
           'title' => 'demo',
           'is_featured' => false,
        ],
        (object)[
           'title' => 'rand',
           'is_featured' => false,
        ]
    ];
   ```

   if this is the case, then our job is two extract the element or 'data row' with the `is_featured` set to `true` from the results set. Another way to do it is to have two queries, one for the non-featured, and another for the featured results, but for now we'll stick with one.
2. In order to extract the "featured" object from the array we need to unset it using its index. To obtain the index we can use something like this:

   ```
    $index = array_search(true, array_column($jobs, 'is_featured'))
   ```
3. Next we use the `$index` to retrieve the "featured" job

   ```
    $featured = $jobs[$index];
   ```
4. then we remove it from the initial results array. After this, `$jobs` will no longer contain the `$featured` job:

   ```
    unset($jobs[$index]);
   ```
5. Finally we create the HTML, we place the `$featured` on top, then loop through the remaning:

   ```
    <ul>
       <li><?= $featured->title ?></li>
       <?php foreach($jobs as $job) { ?>
          <li><?= $job->title ?></li>
       <?php } ?>
    </ul>
   ```

Comment: I do not get what your code would do, can you apply it on my code above?

Comment: Posted a breakdown of the code I provided. Check it out and let me know if you still cant figure it out.